# Telling testthat to work on specific paths in a custom folder structure

Tags: r, testthat

I work in a company which adopts an unortodox way of organizing its folders and I wanted to be able to tell `testthat` in which folder it should look for my functions.
For example, using the following file structure:

```
.
├── data
│   ├── input
│   └── output
└── src
    ├── Ex
    ├── Py
    │   └── tests
    └── R
        └── tests
```

I wanted to tell `testthat`, that all my tests are located in `./src/R/tests`, and my code is in `./src/R/`. Is there a way to specify these paths so the package would know where to look for the files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could `source` the functions to test and use `test_dir`:

```
library(testthat)

path <- 'src/R'
files <- file.path(path,list.files(path,pattern='\\.R$'))
lapply(files,source)

testresults <- test_dir('src/R/tests/testthat',
                 reporter = "list",
                 env = test_env(),
                 start_end_reporter = TRUE,
                 load_helpers = TRUE,
                 stop_on_failure = FALSE)
```

Comment: this `test_dir()` is not running the tests, to be honest it looks like it's doing nothing. It returns an empty list.

Comment: I use automatic tasks running it daily, AFAIK it works perfectly. Are you sure of the absolute path of the test dir? You could check if `file.path` sees files in it.

Comment: One possible misundestanding : it only returns *failed* tests in the list

Comment: Oh, the path was wrong, I replaced your suggestion with `src/R/tests/testthat` and it ran all the tests. One last question: can my tests access other files? Because I have some functions that depend on data stored in other folders of the project.

Comment: You'll have to source the other functions from the other folders. One alternative is to develop a `package`, but this doesn't seem to fit with your requirement because R files have to be in `\R`